# Select column data between () parantheses

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have data in SQL server database column like the following:

```
Column

Ot ntri - Non Cash - (6932)
Otr Contri- Cash - (6930)
anth C-Cash - (6935)
Phil Cor-Non Cash - (6937)
Poll Conh - (6940)
```

I need a query to select data that is present only withing the parantheses ().

Please help:

I need to select only

```
6932
6930
6935
```

etc for the column

Thanks

Comment: why not make a different column for numbers in paranthesis?

Comment: Looks like you'll need to normalise your data first before attempting to query it.

Comment: The query needs to retrieve only the values inside bracket. It may be numeric or character. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A combination of SUBSTRING and CHARINDEX could do this for you:

```
SELECT  * ,
    REVERSE(t.[Column]) AS Reversed ,
    CASE WHEN t.[Column] LIKE '%(%'
              AND t.[Column] LIKE '%)%'
         THEN REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(t.[Column]),
                                CHARINDEX(')', REVERSE(t.[Column])) + 1,
                                CHARINDEX('(', REVERSE(t.[Column]))
                                - CHARINDEX(')', REVERSE(t.[Column])) - 1))
         ELSE NULL
    END AS result
FROM    dbo.[Table] AS t
```

Comment: "Invalid length parameter passed to the SUBSTRING function" I get this message and it retreives only 1000 rows of data actual set is 3000 rows

Comment: for me the query works. what version of SQL Server do you have? does every row contains number + parantheses? if not, the error message you get is reasonable, since CHARINDEX delivers 0 if '(' and ')' is not found, so there will be a negative expression in the second part (substring length)

Comment: Now what If I have data like this EO PI (PI Cod. C0094) - (7B1B1Q) I need data from only the last parantheses to be displayed

Comment: Absolutely not..Thanks a lot...the reqt is such hence the request :)....appreciate the help !!! Thanks :)

Comment: a quick question.. why to use the REVERSE Function. Doesn't it slow down the query?

Comment: Of course it slows down the query, but the requirement was to detect the last paranthesis. Afaik there is no LASTCHARINDEXOF function, so the trick is to reverse the string before the lookup. Of course there exist more elegant solutions (e.g. putting logic into stored procedure/function or first selecting the reverse and than extracting the desired content).

Answer (score 2):

I know you have accepted a good answer. This is another way of doing it. Same functions are used with `CTE`:

[SQL server 2008 fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a5a89/9) to get the string within last brackets.

```
;with cte as (
 select col, charindex(')',reverse(col),1) brk1,
        charindex('(',reverse(col),1) brk2
 from t
)
select col, reverse(substring(reverse(col),brk1+1,brk2-brk1-1)) mystr
from cte
```

Comment: +1 like this approach :) one example for simplifying my solution.